# for loop (f in *.txt) throws error if no *.txt file exists

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have a small bash script which looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in ./*.txt
do
 f=$(basename $f)
 echo "Processing $f"
 scp somewhere
 mv $f done/`basename $f`
done
```

This is working perfectly, but as soon as there are no files left, it will throw  this error: `*.txt: No such file or directory`
I'm wondering why it enters the loop and how I can do this (without a new if maybe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no `*.txt` file, the string remains unexpanded as is and the loop is entered. To prevent that, set the `nullglob` option.

```
shopt -s nullglob
```